# Winforms DataGridView Horizontal ScrollBar to move like Excel

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview with a number of Columns, Some of the Columns are merged together liek Excel using custom code.
I want my Horizontal Scrollbar to move like the Scrollbar in Excel, where the movement is restricted per column basis.

There are 2 types of movement here.
1. Click on the arrow of the Scrollbar to move.
2. Use the Slider to move

I have achieved the 1st requirement, when the user clicks on the arrow, i move the position to the required Column index by setting the property
Grid.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex

Help is required in the 2nd movment, where the user clicks and holds the Slider and moves it.
This movment to be customised so that it the slider does not slide, but does a staggered slide to the next Column directly.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a simple solution, if your columns widths are a single, fixed size:

Set `DataGridView.HorizontalScrollingOffset` to the width of your columns.